# Writing data to remote VPS database

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, vps

I have an issue which may have two possible approaches to getting a solution, im open to either.

I use a 3rd party application to download data daily into pandas dataframes, which I then write into a local postgres database. The dataframes are large, but since the database is local I simply use `df.to_sql` and it completes in a matter of seconds.

The problem is that now I have moved the database to a remote linux server (VPS). The same `to_sql` now takes over an hour. I have tried various values for `chunksize` but that doesn't help much.

This wouldn't be an issue if I could simply install the 3rd party app on that remote server, but the server OS does not use a GUI. Is there a way to run that 3rd party app on the server even though it requires a GUI? (note: it is a Windows app so I use wine to run it on my local linux machine and would presumably need to do that on the server as well).

If there is no way to run that app which requires a GUI on the VPS, then how should I go about writing these dataframes to the VPS from my local machine in a way that doesn't take over an hour? Im hoping there's some way to write the dataframes in smaller pieces or using something other than `to_sql` more suited to this.

A really clunky, inelegant solution would be to write the dataframes to csv files, upload them to the server using ftp, then run a separate python script on the server to save the data to the db. I guess that would work but it's certainly not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating countless possible solutions:

- Creating a tunnel to forward a port from my local machine to the server so it can access the 3rd party app.
- modifying all my python code to manually insert the data from my local machine to the server using `psycopg2` instead of `pandas to_sql`
- Creating a docker container for the 3rd party app that can be run on the server
- and several other dead ends or convoluted less than ideal solutions

In the end, the solution was to simply install the 3rd party app on the server using wine but then ssh into it using the -X flag. I can therefore access the gui on my local machine while it is running on the server.